# Is there a class or sequence diagram for BitcoinCore?

Tags: bitcoin-core-development

I'm looking at the code located at https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/tree/master/src

Does anyone have a basic diagram of what calls what, just a sequence chart of how all the classes piece together and what's a good entry point.  There was a thread with some overview but there has been a lot of change since it seems.  Just wondering if anyone has gone through this process.

Comment: Hi curfewed, I edited your question to make the title a bit more expressive, I hope that it still is aligned with your intent. Please feel free to roll-back or improve my changes, if it isn't. Since you are new to Bitcoin.SE, you might appreciate a look at our [tour].

Answer (score 2):

You can use source code browsing tools like [Source Insight](http://www.sourceinsight.com/)(proprietary) or [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/)(Free software) to create dependency diagram of functions and files.

The doxygen documentation for Bitcoin source can also be found at https://dev.visucore.com/bitcoin/doxygen/